# I Have No Lungs

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *I have no lungs, but I can breathe, 
>  Where you, yourself, cannot. 
>  Via me, the greenwoods seethe, 
>  Where my cheeks will flush when hot. 
>  
>  I have no lungs, but I can drown, 
>  Where you will suffocate. 
>  Find me on the reddest crown, 
>  With the scratch of a duplicate. 
>  
>  I have no lungs, but I can roar, 
>  Where you can only cry; 
>  You would feel your eyes implore, 
>  Some mercy if they are nearby. 
>  
>  Now find the odd one out, and then, 
>  Replace it with itself. 
>  Once you read the verse, again, 
>  May you learn what I call myself.* 
>  
>  ***What am I?***

The answer is a single word, as described in the `word` tag below.

---

**Hint:**

> I have no lungs, but all my tears, 
>  Have hearts: a charge of blue. 
>  When I die, my offspring clears, 
>  And the wax descends into glue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the answer:

> Fire

**Part of the solution:**

I have no lungs, but I can breathe,

 
Where you, yourself, cannot. 

Via me, the greenwoods seethe, 

Where my cheeks will flush when hot.

> Fire needs oxygen but has no lungs.
>  
>  Fire can be used to boil certain things ( I had to search for the meaning of seethe).
>  
>  Hot fire has a red glow.

I have no lungs, but I can drown, 

Where you will suffocate. 

Find me on the reddest crown, 

With the scratch of a duplicate.

> Fire can be put out  with water.

I have no lungs, but I can roar, 

Where you can only cry; 

You would feel your eyes implore, 

Some mercy if they are nearby.

> A huge fire can make a roaring sound.
>  
>  And can make people cry when something like their house is on fire.

Now find the odd one out, and then, 

Replace it with itself. 

Once you read the verse, again, 

May you learn what I call myself.

> No idea really.

Comment: You have the correct answer, but although most of your reasonings are correct, some are not. [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)("Gur ubhfr sver" ernfbavat jnf vapbeerpg, gubhtu vg pbhyq or hfrq nf na nygreangvir.) Also, the last part needs some work, of course. Nonetheless, you are definitely on the right track! $(+1)$

Comment: "Scratch of a duplicate" could be (ROT13) "Qhcyvpngr" vf nabgure jbeq sbe n "zngpu", juvpu lbh fpengpu ntnvafg gur obk gb yvtug naq fgneg n sver. "Gur erqqrfg pebja" pbhyq ersre gb gur zngpu "urnq" (nabgure jbeq sbe urnq vf pebja).

Comment: @Astralbee you are correct. You have officially solved the wordplay part. Now for the easy step: to *match* this finding with the correct paragraph(s).

Comment: Maybe the "I can roar" section is referring to rot13(fbzrbar jub vf ba sver. Guvf jbhyq nyfb rkcynva lbh nfxvat sbe zrepl.)

Comment: @elarr that is not it, but that is another alternative. You might be overthinking it a bit ;)

Comment: Can you give Any hints? :-)

Comment: I made a hint. You might want to look at the third line and @Astralbee 's comment :)

Comment: rot13(nu pnaqyrf)

Comment: Ehh, actually, the third line refers to Rot13(fzbxr, nf jura vg trgf va lbhe rlrf, vg pna fgvat naq znxr "lbhe rlrf vzcyber fbzr zrepl". Ohg gur ragver uvag jnf ersreevat gb pnaqyrf, naljnl.) Congratulations! $\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: Ah, now I see. ( Or maybe not ;-)  ) :'-(

Answer (score 1):

I have no lungs, but I can roar, 
Where you can only cry; 
You would feel your eyes implore, 
Some mercy if they are nearby.

Is this supposed to be

> If you are deserted on an island, you build a fire and hope for someone to see the smoke and rescue you

Using @OfPiR's answer

Comment: Great answer for your very first, but unfortunately, that is not correct. The correct answer is more simpler than that, but I guess yours could work, too. Also, since you are new to this site, I strongly suggest you visit the [**Help Center**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help), particularly the sections about  *Asking* and *Answering* to get an idea of what is posted on the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (Puzzling.SE)**. If you wish to be on this site for as often as everyday, I suggest you also check out the section known as *Our model* and look at the Code of Conduct. Otherwise, $(+1)$! :D